# apt upgrade reporting in bytes and 10000+%

Tags: apt

I have a server running 16.04 and when I run `apt upgrade` it doesn't report the correct package size or percentage:

`76% [1 jenkins 35.5 MB/262 B 13457392%]`

I've also noticed that download speeds are much slower than other servers from the same provider.

What could cause this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check the configuration and the sources.list. Try using the main repositories or nearer mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

So in this peculiar case changing the source package location from `https` to `http` fixed the issue.

Comment: What likely happened is that `apt` went to determine how large the download is, which would be done by inspecting the `Content-Length` header of the HTTP response, but it likely was a redirect (262 bytes) at which point the real download started which was much larger.